# How to use Django ORM to make a query so that it returns the latest entry based on a datetime field in a particular group?

Tags: python, mysql, django, datetime

I have a model with datetime field which is the time stamp of when the row was added and in this model/table continuous entries are being made at certain intervals from various sources which are referenced through a name which is also a field in the model.

I need to form a query so that I will fetch the row with latest datetime when grouped by name.

i.e. lets say for example table is something like this:

```
timestamp              entry_name
22 march 12:30         First
22 march 12:32         Second
22 march 12:42         First
22 march 12:50         Second
```

My query should result in:

```
22 march 12:42         First
22 march 12:50         Second
```

As they are the latest entries with respect to "First" and "Second" group.

Now using raw query its pretty straight forward:

```
select *,max(datetime) from entry_table GROUP BY entry_name;
```

Is there any simple way to do this through the ORM?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my own projects. The order_by and values make it group by name

```
from django.db import models
Model.objects.order_by('name').values('name').annotate(max_timestamp=models.Max("timestamp"))
```

Comment: The problem with this is if I add another parameter to values() then the query will also get added with that parameter in GROUP BY clause which might cause issues.

Comment: You can select values AFTER the annotate query. Just add `.values('something')` behind the annotate call

Comment: Nopes its still adding it to GROUP BY Clause in query even after I select values after annotate query.

Comment: Do you perhaps have any example code of the models?

Comment: @Varenya Django does not support selecting columns that are not in the `GROUP BY` clause, because that's not a valid query in standard SQL (i.e. all of Django's backends except MySQL). Only MySQL has to set its own rules and return an arbitrary value, so if you want an arbitrary value, you'll have to write your own query.